# How to ask NetSuite saved search to return client records, when a related record does not exist, within a date range

Tags: date, netsuite, saved-searches

I have client records that may have related-records indicating they attended a conference. I want to tag client records that have not attended a conference in the last 3 years. They may have conference records prior to 3 years past, but will have none onward from that.

I'm asking Netsuite to search from 3 years ago, and return client records where conference records do not exist.

My question is, how can I get NetSuite to work with a system date range, today-3 years and out into the future, in a saved search?

The first criteria is, for example, 'conference record ID is NULL.'
The date criteria something like, 'after today -1095 days.'

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by adding a 'Formula (Date)' filter as a criteria in the saved search. Then, in the description, 'after 3 years ago (relative), and the field typed-in as {today}. This worked to filter the other criteria within the date range.

[image]